# jQuery ajax remote json not working

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

When I enter the url in browser, I get a json response. But I can't access the response using my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q=cars",
    type:"GET",
    crossDomain : true,
    async: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "getStatus",

    success: function(json) {
    },

    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
});

function getStatus(response)
{
    console.log(response.status);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try changing dataType to "json"?

Comment: You never, *never* want to use `async: false` with Ajax requests. There is not one valid use case for that.

Comment: Is the JS function $ already ready and fully loaded the time it is run? Doesnt look like to me

Answer (score 0):

`api.qwant` return JSON, not JSONP. It is also restricted by the `same-origin policy` too. So, you normally have problem accessşng the data through cross-domain ajax requests because of browser security, except you have a [CORS proxy](https://siderite.blogspot.com/2017/03/free-cors-proxies.html) which adds CORS headers in behalf of your and bypasses same-origin policy.

By the way, you can try your function with CORS and JSONP supported API:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    type:"GET",
    jsonpCallback: "getStatus",
    dataType: "jsonp",

});
function getStatus(response)
{
    console.log(response);
}
```

---

**ALSO SEE:**

- [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [JSONP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp)